# Обновление конфигурации: Файл базы данных поврежден

Tags: 1с

Попросила обновление, обновил сначала платформу потом приступил к конфигурации и в итоге конфигурацию обновить не удается возвращается ошибка:

```
Платформа: 1С:Предприятие 8.3 (8.3.13.1644)
Конфигурация: Бухгалтерия предприятия, редакция 3.0 (3.0.66.60) (http://v8.1c.ru/buhv8/)
Copyright (С) ООО "1C-Софт", 2009 - 2018. Все права защищены
(http://www.1c.ru)
Режим: Файловый (без сжатия)
Приложение: Тонкий клиент
Локализация: Информационная база: русский (Россия), Сеанс: русский (Россия)
Вариант интерфейса: Такси

Ошибки:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01.12.2018 8:49:47
Невосстановимая ошибка
Ошибка при выполнении запроса POST к ресурсу /e1cib/logForm:
по причине:
Ошибка СУБД:
Файл базы данных поврежден 'C:\1C\Accounting/1Cv8.1CD'
по причине:
Файл базы данных поврежден 'C:\1C\Accounting/1Cv8.1CD'
```

попробовал

- проверить файл с БД

[image: все нормально, ошибок не обнаружилось]

- почистил временные файлы в

C:\users\<Имя вашего пользователя>\AppData\Local\1C\

C:\users\<Имя вашего пользователя>\AppData\Roaming\1C\1cv8\ кроме папки tmplts

к положительному результату не привело (((

Какие еще есть варианты в решении этой проблемы?

p.s.

проверил возможность физического копирования файла - все ОК, в HDD нет проблемы...

Answer (score 1):

На старой платформе сделай выгрузку базы; Затем зайди в конфигуратор на новой платворме и загрузи базу !

Comment: updater платформы разве делает не подобную же процедуру?

Comment: нет, он только ставит новую версию платформы, к базам данных он не обращается;